# How to use BLAS library in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, blas

I'm new to scala and I'm writing a Spark application in Scala and I need to use the `axpy` function from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS`. However it looks to be not accessible to users. Instead I try to import the `com.github.fomil.netlib` and directly access it. But I could either. I need to multiply to DenseVector.

Answer (score 8):

Right now, the BLAS class within mllib is marked `private[spark]` in the spark [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/BLAS.scala).  What this means is that it is not accessible external to spark itself as you seem to have figured out. In short, you can't use it in your code.

If you want to use netlib-java classes directly, you need to add the following dependency to your project

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.2" pomOnly()
```

That should allow you to import the BLAS class. Note, I haven't really tried to use it, but I am able to execute `BLAS.getInstance()` without a problem. There might be some complexities in the installation on some Linux platforms as described here - https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java.

Answer (score 0):

Add mllib to your project

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.3.0"`

Comment: I do have it in my project, and included the 11org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.BLAS`` but when I write `` BLAS.axpy()`` it says 'axpy` is not a member of BLAS~ I read somewhere that BLAS is not exposed for users. Any alternatives?

Comment: what is giving you this error? The compiler in sbt the console? An ide?

Comment: I'm working in Scala-IDE, it shows an error message and doesn't get compiled.